# pandas dataframe: Selecting rows by variable of floating point range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, range

I am new ty Python and wanted to find a solution to select rows by a variable which should be a range of floating points. As a variable I assign numpy array made with numpy arange since python's built-in range does not take float as step. Here's an example of what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 100], [2,200], [3, 300], [4, 400], [5, 500], 
    [5.5, 550], [6, 600], [6.5, 620]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['small_number', 'big number'])

rng = np.arange(2, 7, 0.1)
df.loc[df.small_number.isin(rng)]
```

Unfortunately, the gives only the first value and does not find other. The output:

```
small_number    big number
1   2.0         200
```

How could I make a float range variable which then will be passed to select DataFrame rows?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need in the output? Do you need to select all rows between 2 and 7? Or do you want to create separate groupings, one for values between 2 and 2.1, another between 2.1 and 2.2, ...?

Comment: Why use a range for this?

Comment: the issue is the numbers in `rng` are not exact, for example `3.0` might actually be stored as `3.0000001` in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to round in order to check for existence in the array. The float numbers in the array are not precise as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

```
When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent.
```

In this case we can use [`np.around`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) and round to one decimal place.

```
df.loc[df.small_number.isin(np.around(rng, decimals=1))] 

   small_number  big number
1           2.0         200
2           3.0         300
3           4.0         400
4           5.0         500
5           5.5         550
6           6.0         600
7           6.5         620
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed now that if you make a list from np.arange it will show the full values.